# JS - Focus/Select Cursor Again after Toggling Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a landing page with two forms, only one form visible at a tme. The first form is an age-verification form and if the conditions are met I use jQuery `.toggle()` to switch to the next form. On page load, for good UX I am using `.focus()` to put the cursor in the first form field with this line of code: `$("input[name='month']").focus();`

```js
// Focus cursor on first input field

$("input[name='month']").focus();

var age = 19;
// After calculating age based on user input, toggle the elements

if (age >= 18) {
  $('#age-verification').toggle();
  $('#subscribe').toggle();
} else {
  $('#age-verification').html('<h2>Sorry, you must be at least 18 years old.</h2>');
}
```

```html
<div id="age-verification">
   <h2>Must be 18, please verify age</h2>
   <input type="number" name="month" />
   <input type="number" name="day" />
   <input type="number" name="year" />
   <button id="age-gate-submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<form id="subscribe" action="#" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="email" />
   <input type="text" name="zip" />
   <button id ="subscribe" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

How can I use either `.select()`, `focus()` or other method to place the cursor in the first field of the second form `<input type="text" name="email" />` after the `.toggle()` event? I've tried placing a `.focus()` event direct after the `.toggle()` which seemed logical but not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first hide the subscribe form:

```
$('#subscribe').hide();
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/kihepujewi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works but i'm a little confused. My div was already set to `display: none`, so why do I need to use `.hide()` first?

Comment: @JoelB I believe the only other real change I made was hard coding the age variable which you said would be retrieved via user input.

Comment: I have that code on my side but it's definitely helpful to post it here for the example. Thank You!